# Error while hitting 3rd party API from Spring boot app : the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, keystore, truststore, cacerts

I have a spring boot application (running on HTTPS but on self-signed cert). It uses JDK 1.8 (not open JDK) and I wrote down a code where my code is hitting 3rd party APIs. Earlier my code was working. But for some other task, I had to import Company provided certificate to make application HTTPS. For this, I changed keystore from JKS to PCKS12 standard.

Now after changing the keystore (I did this to enable my application HTTPS with company provided certificate), my code which hits 3rd party API is not working. This is throwing below error.

***Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty***

Can you please help me how to fix this error. I checked on internet and found out that I should set up trust store in my application but not able how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to fix this. By Adding below lines in my code `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "<classpath:file.p12>"); System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","<pwd>"); System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.truststoretype", "PKCS12");`

Comment: You can set these properties inside applications.properties as well.

Comment: Sometimes its useful to run your program under  the strace program on  Ubuntu (its  called truss on other version of unix/linux)  It will list out every system call your application makes.  Most java versions use stat to test a file  existence and open to access it.  You can find out which file your java application has accessed or which class path its using to resolve things.  Sometimes what its actually doing does match what you think its doing.

Comment: Again I am facing this issue. Earlier when I said that it worked I noticed now that it works when code is invoked from main method of stand alone java program but when I start the spring boot project server then it does not work.